# c++ - Creating custom events at runtime

Tags: c++, function, pointers, runtime

I'm creating a 2D RPG game engine in C++ with Allegro. I've reached the point in which i need to implement a scripting system. So, my poblem is this one:

I have a struct called **Event**. Inside this struct there is a function pointer, which points to the function that i want to execute when the event is fired. So, here's an example:

```
struct Event {
    //...
    void (*func)(Player*, void*);
    //...
}
```

Now, to create an event i have this function:

```
Event* Events::register_event_source(int x, int y, std::string name, Player* player, void (*func)(Player*, void*));
```

So, to use it i just need to create a function with this signature:

```
void test_event(Player* p, void* data)
{
    //Do something cool here
}
```

and then register an event source, giving the address to that function:

```
//...
Player* player = new Player(0, 0);
//...
Event* evt = Events::register_event_source(10, 10, "test event", player, &test_event);
//Eventually set some data for the event
evt->set_data(new std::string("Just some test data"));
```

In this way, when the player goes over the assigned spot (in this case x = 10, y = 10) the event will fire, executing any code in the **test_event** function.

Now, my question is: is it possible to do, or at least to get close to, this process at runtime?? ...i would need to create the function (in this case "test_event") at runtime, but i did some research, and i think what i understood is that it is not really possible to create functions at runtime.
So, which approach should i go for?? ...I know it is an abstract question...but i really don't know how to approach this problem.

Thanks in advice for any help! and sorry for my bad explaining abilities...English is not my language!

Comment: no, you cannot generate code at run-time in C++, but the question is why do you think you need to do that?

Comment: @AndyProwl What i want to do is, having my own scripting language and beeing able to create events in that language. Given that the script will be loaded at runtime, i don't know how to implement it.

Comment: How about using an existing scripting language, like Lua?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to express, you are writing a scripting engine that interprets some logics built at run-time into a string, and this should determine what to do on `Player` and `data`. If so, I can imagine you should have a function like

```
void InterpretScriptCode(Player* p, void* data, string const& code)
```

or something equivalent that interprets and *execute* the logics described in `code` on `p` and `data`.

Then, you can use `std::bind` and `std::function` to encapsulate a call to your scripting engine:

```
// Header <functional> needs to be included, and a proper "using namespace"
// directive must be present for bringing placeholders _1 and _2 into scope

std::function<void(Player*, void*)> fxn = std::bind(
    &InterpretScriptCode,
     _1,
     _2,
    "int x = 0; ... blah blah" // this should be your run-time generated script
    );
```

And pass `fxn` in input to your `register_event_source()` function.

Btw, you might be interested in using Boost.Signals/Boost.Signals2 for realizing event registration/handling.

If you are not using C++11, you can use `boost::bind` and `boost::function` instead of `std::bind` and `std::function`.

Comment: Boost.Signals2 is definitely worth to check in this case. The same about Lua.

Comment: So, in other words, the only way is to reinterpret the script every time the event gets fired? ...couldn't this get slow at some point?

Comment: @Sylar: I do not see much room for other opportunities here: it's scripting, so yes, there's nothing else you can do in regular C++ than interpret it. you cannot compile it on-the-fly into C++ code. What you *could* do is to have your interpreter invoke a (C++?) compiler to compile your runtime-generated (C++?) code into something like a temporary DLL to be loaded by your main C++ program. Feasible, but pretty complex (and likely bug-prone). Maybe a scripting engine would do that, not sure.

Comment: @AndyT I know i should check Lua, but i find it extremely challenging doing everything by myself...and, as i program just for fun and not for job, i never take the easy path! I just enjoy coding a lot! ...of course, if i was doing a commercial project, i would consider using Lua!

Comment: @AndyProwl i think i'll give the scripting engine a try...i'm still too new to C++ to try that second option, although it seems really fun! ...and i will look for some info about Signals and std::bind/std::function ...it seems pretty interesting! Thanks for the help!